# SQL or R: Find and display the index of all '1's from a column with binary data type and store in another 1 or more columns

Tags: mysql, r, indexing, binary

I am using a table called 'data_1' and one column 'col_1' has binary data type (Ex, 1100000).

I would like to obtain the position(index) of all '1's from this column and store them in another 1 or more columns.

Output can be:

1) 'col_2' stores value 6 and 7, indicates there are '1's at index 6 and 7.

2) Or we can store output in multiple columns 'pos_1', 'pos_2', 'pos_3', 'pos_4', 'pos_5', 'pos_6', 'pos_7' with value (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), meaning there are '1's at index 6 and 7, and rest positions are '0'.

How can we implement in mysql or in R?

I have tried:

In R, I have tried the following function applied to 'col_1' but it didn't work.

```
    convert_to_binary <- function(n) {
      if(n > 1) {
        convert_to_binary(as.integer(n/2))
      }
      cat(n %% 2)
    }

    data_1$col_2 <- convert_to_binary(data_1$col_1)
```

In MySQL, the following only returns the first '1'

```
select POSITION(1 IN col_1) as col_2 from data_1;
```

Any suggestions here?

Thanks!

Comment: "store them in another 1 or more columns" -- spraying an array across columns is 'bad' schema design.

Comment: What is the datatype of the MySQL column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in R:

```
col_1<-c(1100000, 1100001, 1100100)

data_1 <- data.frame(col_1)

as.character(data_1$col_1) -> data_1$col_1

position<-function(x){unlist(gregexpr(pattern ='1',x))}

data_1$col_2 <- sapply(data_1$col_1, function(x) position(x))

as.character(data_1$col_2) -> data_1$col_2
gsub(":", ",", data_1$col_2) -> data_1$col_2
gsub("c", "", data_1$col_2) -> data_1$col_2
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in MySQL assuming the numbers are 7 characters in length. You can add more `SUBSTRING` expressions if feasible.

```
SELECT
col_1,
SUBSTRING(col_1, 1,1) AS pos_1,
SUBSTRING(col_1, 2,1) AS pos_2,
SUBSTRING(col_1, 3,1) AS pos_3,
SUBSTRING(col_1, 4,1) AS pos_4,
SUBSTRING(col_1, 5,1) AS pos_5,
SUBSTRING(col_1, 6,1) AS pos_6,
SUBSTRING(col_1, 7,1) AS pos_7
FROM data_1;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT
col_1,
CONCAT_WS(",", 
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(col_1, 1,1)=1 THEN 1 END,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(col_1, 2,1)=1 THEN 2 END,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(col_1, 3,1)=1 THEN 3 END,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(col_1, 4,1)=1 THEN 4 END,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(col_1, 5,1)=1 THEN 5 END,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(col_1, 6,1)=1 THEN 6 END,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(col_1, 7,1)=1 THEN 7 END) AS col_2
FROM data_1;
```

Comment: Thanks! In this way, we only need to make them the same length as a prior step.

Comment: @CrubalChenxiLi Correct. I added one more approach that only adds col_2